# iPhone Trying to do a block animation on a UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios

Im trying to make a memory game.  I would like it such that, when a button is pressed it will show an animation of the image turning into another image.  I have put some test code on the onceat method,
there is no error, but....nothing happens, no animation
code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    // display house
    //   mHouseNumber=SignTranslation[r];
    //  NSNumber *convert=[ NSNumber numberWithInt:mHouseNumber];
    //  mHouse.text=[convert stringValue];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2]; 

    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut ];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView: mButtona.imageView cache:YES];
     mButtona.imageView.image =  [ UIImage imageNamed :@"feet1.jpg"]; //end 
    [UIView commitAnimations];  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> In iOS 4 and later, use the block-based animation methods. (Recommended)

From Apple's documentation in regards to the beginAnimations (etc) methods found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW131). Use the various [animateWithDuration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW111) functions.

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{ 
    //Add your animation code here 
    } 
 }];
```

I would also set the UIImageView's [highlightedImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006889-CH3-SW17) and simply animate the the highlight inside of the animation block.